# Is there a financial motivation for organizing a summer school?

Tags: summer-school

Do professors and scientific staff of an institute make money from summer schools?

Or is it a well-intentioned unpaid activity done by organizers?

For example, a summer school about a topic in mathematics.

Comment: What I see at large universities in the U.S.: summer school programs, e.g. for high school students, bring in revenue.  Many of the university's costs are fairly fixed.  Many dorms would otherwise by empty in the summer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whithin the universities that I've been affiliated outside the US, there is no financial gain in a math department organizing a summer school, as there is no tuition.

Usually, they should submit a proposal for a funding agency that will cover the costs of the project.

The reason for doing summer schools is for advertising the department and their graduate program outside their regional area. The department may also be interested in boasting a particular research project/area.

One can also squeeze a few activities in the project with a collaborator far away, so the project would also serve for other research activicies not publicly advertised, by paying for his/her visit.

Comment: So, that is, all organizers work unpaid? I mean, an organizer could change his position to another institute and the advertising the department does not make sense for him.

Comment: Maybe in the US it is different, as they don't get a regular salary during the summer, so I believe one can get paid by the school for organizing a summer school. But in other places these would be already part of their regular job. An outsider would get paid by the funding project, depending on the type of work he would be doing in the summer school (say, teaching).